# When mouse select on autocomplete page jump to top

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

When the user selects autocomplete option (while choosing from suggested list) in Chrome - the page jumps (scrolls automatically). How can I fix this? Thanks.

I tried scrollIntoView: false,

Look here: http://www.biletall.com/default.aspx;

Please write "Kayseri" on bus panel and click on the suggested autocomplete value.
You can see the page jump.

**Sample Code:**

```
function ucak_varis_getir(sonuc) {

var data = $.parseJSON(sonuc);
$(function () {

    $('#HavaVaris').autocomplete(
    {
        highlightClass: "bold-text", 
        source: function (request, response) {
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            response($.grep(data, function (value) {
                value = value.label || value.value || value;
                return matcher.test(value) || matcher.test(normalize(value));
            }));

        },
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        scrollIntoView: false,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#HavaVaris').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#HavaVaris').data('ulkeId', ui.item.actor.ulkeId);
            $('#HavaVaris').data('kod', ui.item.actor.kod);
            $('#HavaVaris').data('hiddenData', ui.item.actor.hiddenData);
            yasliGosterGizle();

            return false;
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $('#HavaVaris').data('aramaYapildiMi', 0);
        },
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $('#HavaVaris').data('aramaYapildiMi', 1);
        }

    }).focus();

});

}
```

Comment: Please share some code. At the moment, what you're asking and the source of the problem are unclear.

Comment: On Chrome when user select an item of autocumplete box with mouse;page jumps and I don't want it.If user select with "enter" doesn't jump.

Comment: Again, please post the problematic code here so that it's clear what needs to be addressed.

Comment: This code is for plane search panel

Comment: @jonafato On the site, when selecting the location in textbox, there is a google like suggestion list that appears. When it is selected (clicked), the page jumps a little downwards which Mehmet  doesn't want to happen

Comment: Definitely that I want.sory for bad language.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed is that the problem is only happening on click and not if the user selects using the keyboard.

Try removing **.focus()** near the end of your function.

If it does not work also try changing autoFocus to false.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but, I need that when user press enter it must autocomplete with first suggestion.This is my boss's wishes :). Also when I remove nearest .focus() this time doesn't trigger of autocomplete widget

Comment: Ok.. I don't see anything else here which is leading to this behaviour. Please have a look if there is some other function being called on 'click' event. Selection via keyboard (going up and down via arrows) and pressing enter is not leading to jump.

Comment: @MehmetAkifÖzkök found the offender?

Comment: No I couldn't. updated jquery versiyon but not solution.I think this cause from iframe.Debugged and when jquery-ui.js the page jumps.

Answer (score -1):

Look here: https://www.bibiletal.com/ucak-bileti/

Please write "Kayseri" on bus panel and click on the suggested autocomplete value. You can see the page jump.